# What's the best way to model organic shapes?

Tags: modeling

For eg: I have this sandal I'm trying to get the edges to curl upward slightly as well as the whole toe (as seen in the insert). Try as I have over and over -- trying to deform the mesh shape using proportional editing is just not cutting it!

Any suggestions?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The current topology cannot benefit that. The basic workflow and recommended topology would be:

1. Create the base mesh for the sole.
2. Add a **Subdivide Surface** modifier, then apply.
3. Add another **Subdivide Surface** modifier. Tweak mesh shape with **Proportional Editing**.
4. Build the straps with operations such as **Extrude**, **Bridge** and **Loop Cut**.
5. Build other details, such as thickness.
6. Finally refine the shape.

[image]

Example file: [image]

Comment: This is absolutely BRILLIANT! Thank you Leon!

Comment: I will model this today... Q: Can I section parts of this to add a bump map?

Comment: Yes, but no need to separate the mesh. You can select that part then apply a new material with a new texture with a new UV. :)

Comment: Damn This one is too good! i got a blenderfreeze!