# What skills are required to model / sculpt this head?

Tags: modeling, sculpting

I came across this image in a dutch newspaper and I would like to know how you would create this head in Blender ? What kind of skills do I have to learn ? What are the most important techniques to be used ? Or can it be done much better in another software package ?

[image]

Comment: I would use "Make Human" http://www.makehuman.org/ and import the resulting model into Blender. I've never used Make Human so I can't instruct you on how to do this. (I think it's relatively simple to use).

Comment: It should be possible to do in Blender. You should use basic modeling (blocking the shape of the head), sculpting (refining the head), lighting (to not ruin results of materials / compositing it's good idea to setup lighting in the beginning), materials, rendering and compositing (to enhance results of lighting and rendering).

Comment: Ok Guys, maybe this question is too broad, But have you seen the fabulous answer of Stacker ? I guess this is very valuable info for me and many others. And where should I post this question, if not here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already mentioned in the comments, make human is the shortcut.
A  shape created by this awesome tool in two minutes, limited in details but could be tuned wihtin blender:

[image]

Another way to re-create this with modelling either trace the contours of a background image. Or use subdividing, insets and proportinal editing:

[image]

[image]

After ripping <kbd>V</kbd> the mouth, the mesh could be easily adjusted to whatever head shape you want. Kudos to [What's the best way to model organic shapes?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/45925/whats-the-best-way-to-model-organic-shapes/45940#45940)

[image]
[image]

You might also need this addon: http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/Add_Mesh/Add_Gear

Comment: WOW !! this really helps :) you should have waited 15 min, then you could have the bounty premium ;)